# Python etree iterfind trying to pass variable to function string

Tags: python, xml

I can not find the appropriate syntax or method to do this, which is why I am reaching out.

I am using python 2.7 lxml etree

my code is similar to this:

```
for y in mytree.iterfind('./level1/level2/level3/[2]'):
  print y.tag, y.text
```

Essentially printing all of the available tags and text in the second iteration of the level.  (I know how many there are, I am not having issues with indexing or making the function work).

I am attempting to loop through them using 'i' as a defined variable (incrementally increasing 'i' to the defined number of items).

This does not work:

```
for y in mytree.iterfind('./level1/level2/level3/[i]'):
  print y.tag, y.text
```

I also tried creating the string as a variable (concatenating the text with the 'i variable as a string, but python did not recognize that it was a function anymore.

Any suggestions or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to build the path string using the value of i, e.g (untested):

```
for y in mytree.iterfind('./level1/level2/level3/[%d]'%(i)):
  print y.tag, y.text
```

If in doubt, construct the string outside the interfind call so you can print it, e.g. (untested):

```
for i in range(3): # or whatever the i loop is...
    pathstr = './level1/level2/level3/[%d]'%(i)
    print pathstr
    for y in mytree.iterfind(pathstr):
        print y.tag, y.text
```

Comment: Awesome, that worked perfectly.  I have to learn how that works, meaning the syntax with the %d and %I.  I have experience working with macros so searching for this will work now that you pointed me in the right direction by giving me the answer.  I am still very new to python.  I appreciate the help!

Comment: Do note: [`str.format` is preferred to the modulo operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5082452/1422451) which the latter is used here.